# Looking for a PersistJS type plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, storage, local

Looking for a plugin that functions like PersistJS.  The popular plugins I've found so far are "jStore" by Eric Garside and jStorage by Andris Reinman.  What those two are missing is a fallback for a browser that does not support any local db which PersistJS does using cookies.  I could just refactor PersistJS for jQuery but wanted to check to see if anyone knows of one that already exists.

Looking for the plugin to include...

- Local storage
- google gears
- whatwg
- global storage
- flash
- ie userdata
- cookie if all else fails

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Just because your site is using jQuery doesn't mean every single thing you do has to integrate into it. Just use PersistJS as is. We're using it in a project and it works great.

The guys from [appendTo](http://appendto.com/) just released their [amplify](http://amplifyjs.com/) component library, designed to integrate with jQuery sites. One of the components is [amplify.store](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) which may be what you're looking for.

One of the benefits of amplify.store over PersistJS is that it allows you to add your own custom storage mechanisms.

Comment: I understand that but it is a couple years old and could use some refactoring for speed and size.

Comment: @REK Okay, if there's a problem with the library as is that's another matter, but that's not what you said in your question.

Comment: Also, there seems to be a fork of PersistJS [here](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js) that has fairly recent activity. Not sure how much improved the fork is, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a light plugin (1,2k) to use Local and Session Storage having compatibilty with old browsers use this:

https://github.com/artberri/jquery-html5storage